# Getting which users shared a post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share, feed

With the graph api, when I query for the feed of a user or page, there are some posts that have been shared by users, and I can see the data about the number of shares within the data section of one entity:

```
  "shares": {
    "count": 2
  },
```

When browsing facebook, on that post, when I click on the icon that represents "show shares", something pops up that lets me see some users that shared the post, according to the comment "You can see only shares that are public or from friends."
So is there a way to get the user data from the shares with the graph api?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of all the shares of a facebook post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11491908/get-a-list-of-all-the-shares-of-a-facebook-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't provide information about users who have shared a post / link. Its probably something they will add in the future, but it's not possible at the moment. Your best bet for this information is to scrape the UI to get this information, but you will run into lots of issues and it's probably not worth the effort.

Facebook does give information on who Likes and Comments on posts however, if its any consolation.

Comment: Update: You can do it via "graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/sharedposts" connection.

Comment: yeah but what is an "object" ? thats totally unclear (to me) :D

Comment: A object can be anything: a status update, link, photo, person / user.