# List of shares in FB graph api

Tags: facebook, graph

I am trying to get a list of all users who share a given object on Facebook using the graph api.

There's been some useful info in this regard on stack exchange, here: [Getting which users shared a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499088/getting-which-users-shared-a-post) and here: [List of people who shared on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748037/list-of-people-who-shared-on-facebook)

I experimented with the graph api's /{object-id}/sharedposts endpoint on the api. When I make the api call with a given object id which I have verified has been shared over 100 times (according to the /{page-id}/feed endopoint I am getting the object id from for said post), the api result invariably returns as such:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

So I am getting an empty array...is this because my access token will not allow me to get this information? I am not friends with any of the users sharing the post nor have I 'liked' the page in which the post originates from.

Just wondering if this is an authentication issue or if there's a different problem that I am running into. I've tried it with a few object IDs so I would like to ascertain exactly why there is no data when I use the /{object-id}/sharedposts endpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: it is surely not possible to get a list, that would be a privacy issue.

Comment: not to get too philosophical, but isn't allowing us to get comments and likes out of the api also an equal privacy issue? I will just assume that it is because of authentication that I am getting the empty array then. Thanks!

Comment: you are right, i missed that it was about a page. in that case it should be possible imho. only user profiles are secured, pages are public anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There was a comment recently added to a response on the [List of people who shared on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748037/list-of-people-who-shared-on-facebook) post you referenced that solved this issue for me.

An access token with `read_stream` permissions is required, even if you have other permissions like `read_insights`.  I was getting the same results as you until I added the `read_stream` permission.

However, you still may not get all or any of the shared posts. To see a share, it either has to be shared publicly or you must have permission to view that person's shared post.